# Why is there "state" when there is "nonce" in Sign in with Apple

Tags: ios, apple-sign-in, sign-in-with-apple

In iOS 14, Apple introduced a variable called "state" when using Sign in with Apple.  [The documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/asauthorizationappleidcredential/3153036-state)

We can use it to stop replay attacks. The difference between State and Nonce is that we can check state in the client to make sure it is not a repeated response, and Nonce is to be used in our backend.
My question is that why do we have this state variable when we could just use Nonce both on the client and the backend?

Comment: I am asking myself the same question. Why checking Nonce on backend if we check state in app ? I can just tell you that Nonce can't be checked in app, because it is in the JWT token that you should not decrypt in app.

Comment: @vmeyer why can't we check Nonce in the app? Decrypting JWT is pretty easy.

Comment: Yes you can decrypt JWT and check Nonce in your app. But your app should not have to decrypt JWT in my opinion.